# Name this digraph

Tags: graph-theory, automata-theory

I am trying to track down the name of this digraph and some references:

You take all members of the transformation semigroup on $n$  elements, $T_{n}$.

For two members $x$ ,$y$ ; if $x$  is in the semigroup generated by y then you put an arrow from $y$  -> $x$ . You would read this as "$x$  is in the semigroup generated by $y$". Alternatively $y^k = x$.

What is the name of this digraph? References would be great.

If you wanted to visualize it, the symmetric group $S_{n}$ would be one of the connected components. The sinks are idemptent transformations like (0,1,2,3), (1,1,1,1), ...

Comment: Just found this article. Digraphs and the semigroup of all functions on a finite set, by Peter M. Higgins, Glasgow J. Math. 30 (1988), pp. 41-57

Comment: This article isn't what I am looking for as the transformations are the vertices in my digraph, not the elements 0...n-1 as in this paper.

Comment: I asked a question [Cayley graph of semigroups](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/113132/17111) on Math SE. I hope it would be somewhat helpful to you.

Comment: I've never heard of this digraph before, sorry.  It's quite a strange object.  Sure, $S_n$ is a connected component, but the only strongly connected components are the cyclic subgroups.  How did you come across this, and can you give me a reason to believe it's somehow a useful way of viewing $T_n$, or interesting for some other reason?

Comment: I am deriving combinatorial properties of this graph in the domain of software testing. If you know your state space is a semigroup $a->b$ means you don't have to test $b$ if you have already tested $a$. I hammered out a lot of properties for Sn, http://oeis.org/A186202 ; now I am tackling Tn. Before submitting it to a journal I wanted to get all the canonical semigroup terms correct.

Comment: I am aware of the Green relation digraphs, but mine doesn't seem to be any of them: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_relations

Comment: Ah, sorry, I only just saw this, because I wasn't notified of your reply.  What do you mean exactly by the 'Green relation digraphs'?  (The left and right Cayley graphs of a semigroup give you all the information about ${\cal R}$ and ${\cal L}$, but I haven't seen digraphs for the other Green's relations.)

Comment: The Green relations are the only other graph over the transformation semigroup I was aware of in the literature. I see no reason why you couldn't define the Green relation edges in terms of the digraph I am asking about since it should have all the information required in it's structure.